# Get Page ID from Address Bar With PHP

Tags: php

I have a photo gallery and i'm trying to get and show some photo information from a php file and database. problem is, i have to get photo id from address bar, this is address:

```
http://localhost/fa/index.php?do=photo&a=showphoto&photoid=155
```

in this link photo id is **155**

then, in PHP file i tried this:

```
$photo_id = $_REQUEST["photoid"];
```

but it's not working.

how i can get photo id from page address?

Comment: Define not working. Whathappens when you var_dump($_REQUEST) and var_dump($photo_id)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not use `$_REQUEST` as it will look for a value you request between POST, GET and COOKIE data. It can flaw your site security.

To get data from url use GET data, in this case `$_GET['photoid']`. To display it on the screen use `echo $_GET['photoid']`.

You can also dump all GET data by using this `print_r($_GET)` and you will get an array of GET data dumped.

Comment: thank you so much for information. i have to wait 7 minutes to accept your answer lol

Comment: You're very welcome. You should do some more reading on GET and POST data. You can read a simple PHP manual over here http://www.w3schools.com/php/ as well as you can always look for function reference on http://php.net. Mind that the comments on function pages contain a lot of useful information as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try `$_GET['photoid']`, using the more specific superglobal.

Comment: @Alireza: It should. This is the correct way. There is something else wrong with your code.

Comment: Are you sure PHP is running?